# Is isDirty() method not supported in grails mongodb

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-2.3

Is `isDirty()` method not supported in grails mongodb plugin? I saw a comment in [this](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GPMONGODB-114?focusedCommentId=69898&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-69898) link but it was commented 2 years ago. Just to know, if current version supports it?

Using grails 2.3.5 with mongodb 3.0.1 and no hibernate installed.

Comment: Yes, actually I tried it after. But its behavior is a bit different. It returns true if I assign one property value same as its current value. Also dirty detection doesn't works for embedded data.

Comment: Shashank, looks like mongodb 3.0.1 is working for you. Please view my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278975/cant-run-grails-app-with-mongodb-plugin-version-3-0-3 in case you have also encountered my issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay got it working. It works but has a different behavior. If an existing property is binded & there is no any change in the value after binding then, `isDirty()` returns true. But if property is not at all binded then `isDirty()` works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write something like `User.collection?.findOne(this.id)?.password != password`. It detects if the `password` field has changed.

Comment: Thank you Alexander for your response but following your code will make another query to the database. Also, since I wanted to use the isDirty() method in a database event, it may fail for locking exception.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Aha. So what exactly did you do to make `isDirty()` work?

Comment: `isDirty()` method works but in a bit different fashion like I mentioned in my above answer which was not exactly solving my problem. So I dig into the  grails data mapping code for grails data core and mongodb and I found that, there is a property available in domain instance named `$changedProperties`in the pre-update event. I used that to compare the value and get to know if the particular field has an updated value.

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal so why not post is as an answer here?