# Can't run Grails app with mongodb plugin version 3.0.3

Tags: mongodb, grails, grails-plugin, grails-2.3, mongo-java-driver

I'm trying to upgrade my mongodb plugin from 2.0.1 to 3.0.3. However I keep getting the following error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/mongodb/AggregationOptions
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2531)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1855)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3$1.run(CachedClass.java:84)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:81)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass$3.initValue(CachedClass.java:79)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.getLocked(LazyReference.java:46)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.util.LazyReference.get(LazyReference.java:33)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedClass.getMethods(CachedClass.java:250)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.populateMethods(MetaClassImpl.java:343)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.fillMethodIndex(MetaClassImpl.java:293)
    at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.initialize(MetaClassImpl.java:3048)
    at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.initialize(ExpandoMetaClass.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.ClassInfo.getMetaClassUnderLock(Cl
    ...
```

I've tried changing the version of the plugin to 3.0.2 but the error persists.

UPDATE:

I'm on Grails `2.3.11`.

I've tried including the plugin with specifying no dependencies and also copy pasting the dependencies from my past configuration which is:

```
 dependencies {

        runtime "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.11.4"
        compile "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.11.4"
        runtime "com.gmongo:gmongo:1.2"

    }
```

and

```
 plugins {

        ...

        compile(':mongodb:2.0.1') {
            excludes 'mongo-java-driver', 'gmongo'
        }
```

Comment: Can you please show me your BuildConfig.groovy's dependency? Also which version of grails you are using?

Comment: @ShashankAgrawal Question updated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update your BuildConfig a bit:

```
compile ":mongodb:3.0.2"
```

Don't specify any other mongo related dependencies and don't exclude `mongo-java-driver` or `gmongo`. Also, if you are using mongeez plugin then you have to exclude the java driver.

```
compile (":mongeez:0.2.3") {
    excludes("mongo-java-driver")
}
```

Comment: 3 months later, this seems to be the best solution! I thought it didn't work the first time but it does now!

Answer (score 2):

changing dependencies to:

```
runtime "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.3"

compile "org.mongodb:mongo-java-driver:2.12.3"
```

works

Comment: Thanks! What was added to `2.12.3` that wasn't available in `2.11.4`?