# What is the difference in dirty detection methods isDirty() & hasChanged() for GORM with MongoDB

Tags: grails, grails-orm

For dirty checking in [Gorm for MongoDB](http://gorm.grails.org/latest/mongodb/manual/index.html#dirtyChecking), the doc says to use `hasChanged()` method which works fine. But the GORM entity also supports the traditional method `isDirty()` method.

What are the main differences between both methods? If any, which one to prefer?

Tried to search the repository and found the [`isDirty()`](https://github.com/grails/gorm-mongodb/blob/v7.3.0/grails-datastore-gorm-mongodb/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/mapping/mongo/engine/AbstractMongoObectEntityPersister.java#L83) & [`hasChanged()`](https://github.com/grails/grails-data-mapping/blob/v7.3.2/grails-datastore-core/src/main/groovy/org/grails/datastore/mapping/dirty/checking/DirtyCheckable.groovy) implementation but not sure which one to use with MongoDB.

Past references-

- [Is isDirty() method not supported in grails mongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24729642/is-isdirty-method-not-supported-in-grails-mongodb)
- [Can't run Grails app with mongodb plugin version 3.0.3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29278975/cant-run-grails-app-with-mongodb-plugin-version-3-0-3)

Comment: I'm using `@MongoEntity`'s `isDirty()` and `isDirty(prop)` methods and they work like charm and never head of `hasChanged()`. I guess that both `hasChanged()` and `isDirty()` can be used interchangeably

Comment: I also got to know about `hasChanged()` today and found it confusing. So thought of asking.

Comment: It seems to me, both methods were implemented independently without one favoring over the other. Worth asking @jeffscottbraun

Comment: "Worth asking @jeffscottbraun" - He might know.  I do not.

Comment:  Thanks @JeffScottBrown. Anything you would like to add more?

Comment: "Thanks @JeffScottBrown. Anything you would like to add more?" - I really don't know the answer.  You could look over the code.  It has been a few years since I worked on any of that, and don't think I did any work on the Mongo stuff.  I am sorry that I can't be of help.

Comment: No worries, @JeffScottBrown. Will dig deeper.